# Incorrect write of ONLY last line of a file

Tags: arrays, printing, tabs, newline

THE ISSUE
I read a Windows directory for a group of numbered, tab-delimited .tmp files (i.e. NSW1.tmp, NSW2.tmp, etc.) & load the file names into an array.

Note: Each .tmp file has a blank line at the end of each file.

I then open/read each file line-by-line, perform something on 3 elements & then rewrite the original line + 3 new variables ($capitalised, $result & $racenumber) to the end of each line in a .txt file. All lines gets written correctly except for the last line of each file (i.e. the last 3 variables in the last line get written to the next line, as follows).

> Geelong   Race 1  18  34374   THE ULTIMATUM   8   cdw MICHAEL HIBBS   SALLY
> WYNNE 58  76  87  11  The Ultimatum   18
>
> Geelong   Race 1  19  221x0   BROWN BURBERRY  7   dw  JOHN MOLONEY    BRENTON
> AVDULLA a 58  57  67  10  Brown Burberry  19
>
> Geelong   Race 1  20  07061   STREET CRIER    11  TcDW    PETER JAQUES    JAMIE
> MOTT  58  63  90
>
> 27    Street Crier    20

In the example above, the last 3 variables in the last line, "27 Street Crier 20", get written to the next line. This ONLY occurs when writing the last line for each file. All prior lines written get written correctly.

Note: The .tmp files have a newline at the end of each file (blank line). If I manually remove the blank line at the end of each file, the script works.

Note2: The PRINT statement is crude, I know, so I'll take any suggestions on how to refine it.

THE SCRIPT

```
use Cwd;

$dir = getcwd;

$tab = "\t";
    
$final = "-FINAL";

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while ($file = readdir(DIR)) {

   # Only read in files here (-f = file is a 'plain file').

   next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

   # Use a regular expression to find only files ending in .tmp that do not have a '-' in the filename.Note the use of the + ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) after the character class. Indicates inputs with a length greater than or equal to 1.  
   next unless ($file =~ m/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.tmp$/); 

   # Set variable for the state where the files are from (i.e. NSW, VIC, etc.). 
   $filecheck = substr($file, 0, 3); 
  
   # Push files into an array for each state.   
   push @array,$file; 

   foreach (@array) {

      open INFILE, $file or die "$nofile\n";

      # Remove .tmp extension from files & save filename for creation of new .txt files.

      $filein = $file;

      $filein =~ s/.tmp//;

      $fileout = "$filein$final.txt";   
  
      # Extract the race number from each filename with /(\d+)/ read for each race (i.e. NSW1.tmp). To be added to the 2nd column of output file.

      ($racenumber) = $filein =~ /(\d+)/;

      open (OUTFILE, ">$fileout"); 

      # Go through the file line by line.  
  
      while (my $line = <INFILE>) 

      {

         # Split the current line on tabs.

         my @words = split(/\t/, $line);

         # Set the horse name from uppercase to proper (i.e. capitalise 1st letter of each name).

         my $capitalized = join '', map { ucfirst lc } split /(\s+)/, $words[4];

         # Subtract the predicted rating from the current rating.

         my $result = $words[11]-$words[10];

         my $racenumber = $words[2];  
 
print "$words[0]$tab$words[1]$tab$words[2]$tab$words[3]$tab$words[4]$tab$words[5]$tab$words[6]$tab$words[7]$tab$words[8]$tab$words[9]$tab$words[10]$tab$words[11]$tab$result$tab$capitalized$tab$racenumber\n"; 
    
print OUTFILE "$words[0]$tab$words[1]$tab$words[2]$tab$words[3]$tab$words[4]$tab$words[5]$tab$words[6]$tab$words[7]$tab$words[8]$tab$words[9]$tab$words[10]$tab$words[11]$tab$result$tab$capitalized$tab$racenumber\n"; 
  
      }

   }

}


close INFILE;

close OUTFILE;

closedir(DIR);

exit;
```

Comment: Please edit your post with correct syntax highlighting. See guidelines for posts on stackoverflow

Comment: THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED. I have written the following script to strip out the last CFLR at the end of each .tmp file with the following code:              my @files = grep ( -f ,<*.tmp>);
foreach $file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
   system("perl -pi.bak -e \"chomp if eof\" $file ");
}